# Node readline with an async API call, how to know when to close()

Tags: javascript, readline

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const readLine = require('readline')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

  let aylinResponseArray = [];
  let sendLine = readLine.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('my-file.txt'),
  });

sendLine.on('line', (line) => {
//multiple async API calls made here, I push response on my API's done callback.
}).on('close', function() {
console.log('finished');
  });
  res.end();
});
```

When I go into endpoint and run this, I get finished before everything else. Obviously I am not using async/await principles correctly, would be glad to receive your experience on this.

I have tried different approaches, the one that I found close to what I'm looking for looks like this:

```
const { once } = require('events');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

(async function processLineByLine() {
  try {
    const rl = createInterface({
      input: createReadStream('big-file.txt'),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      // Process the line.
    });

    await once(rl, 'close');

    console.log('File processed.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Yet i'm receiving a transpiling error from node stating that `once is not a function`.

I just brought the above as a trial, if you have a simpler solution to my code above, please let me know

Comment: The first readline code is perfectly fine and you are using readline correctly. My guess is you're not waiting for the result of the "multiple async API calls.." -- which is code you are not showing so we have no idea what is wrong with your code. I repeat again - there is nothing wrong with your readline code